# automate iexplorer using selenium web driver in java language?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

First I tried to automate IE using web driver with C# language. It was easy as I just need to download the IEdriver server and rest of the thing I can add from the nuget package manager in Visual Studio C# application.

Now I want to do the same thing using java. I try to search and got some code examples but I am not able to configure the environment for java. Also I did not get any option in visual studio to create this. other documentations are confusing.

if someone can show some direction than it would be helpful to me.

Edit:

I had already downloaded a JDK for java development and I also had IEdriver server. I was hoping to that there is some way to do this in Visual studio.

After checking the answer, it is clear that i have to use eclipse or any other ide for java.

I also had some java code.

```
System.setProperty(“webdriver.ie.driver”, “IEDriverServer.exe”);
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get(“https://mysite");
```

but as my issue was different i did not posted the code.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Eclipse or NetBeans instead of Visual Studio for JAVA.

You can try to refer the steps below may help you to automate IE using selenium web driver in java language.

(1) First you need to download the JDK (JAVA Development kit) from link below.

[Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

(2) Than after you need to download any IDE application. Here we are using Eclipse which you can download form link below.

[Download Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)

Further, you can try to install JDK and Eclipse and configure the environment.

(3) Next you can try download the Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings for JAVA from link below.

[Download Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

you can unzip the package for Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings.

(4) you need to download the Internet Explorer Driver Server from link below.

[Download Internet Explorer Driver Server](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

(5) you can try to launch the Eclipse application.

(6) Go to File tab -> New -> Project -> Java project and try to create a project and give the desire name to it.

(7) Now you can right click on the project in Eclipse application.
Hover the mouse pointer on Build path and click on Configure build path option.
Go to Libraries tab.
Click on Add external JARS.. Button and add all the JAR files from the unzipped folder of Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings.

(8) Add the sample code below to the JAVA project.
package selenium_test;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class new_java_class {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  //add the IE web driver path here..
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\selenium web drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");   

       WebDriver browser = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       //replace the URL of the web page here..
       browser.get("https://example.com/login/");

       WebElement username = browser.findElement(By.name("uname"));                
       username.sendKeys("test_user");

       WebElement password = browser.findElement(By.name("psw"));                
       password.sendKeys("abcd@1234");

       WebElement btn = browser.findElement(By.name("signIn"));                
       btn.click();

}

}
```

Note:-  Above code is just for reference. You need to modify the code based on actual requirements for automating the web page. You may get errors if runs the above code directly.

(9) Now you can run the project.